# Oracle SQL Plus - Query to fetch data in a specific point in time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a situation where I have to pull data from Oracle database at different point in time during a day but there is a condition with this.
For Example, after running the query in the morning at 11 AM, the query fetched 2 records.
When I re-run the same query at 2 PM, the query should return the records excluding the ones which it had fetched in the morning 11 AM execution.

I am playing around with createdinfo.time and timestamps but I am not able to get the results in a single query.

I don't know even if it is possible to use a single query and get the data filtered as mentioned above or I have to use 2 different queries here for 2 different time intervals.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it's possible if the timestamps are recorded correctly. Please include a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: post a [mcve] please - table definitions, sample data, queries attempted

Comment: How are you excluding the rows you're seen before - are you marking them as seen, or just relying on the time? If you have a row inserted with timestamp 10:59:59 but not yet committed, and you query rows < 11:00:00, then that row won't be seen; if you then commit and later query rows >= 11:00:00 and < 14:00:00, it still won't be seen.